# href vs html tag when pointing to url

Tags: html

I'm just learning HTML and trying to figure out whether the tag after the doctype line in the code below should be **html** or **href**. I know that href should be used when referring to url's but also that because there is a closing bracket for `</html>`, therefore there should also be an opening `<html>`. Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

< **html/href** xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
<title>The Title</title>
</head>

<body>
.
.
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it as shown below -

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>MyWorl</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <a href="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >XHTML</a>
    </body>

</html>
```